# javascript/React: Check if date is more than 24 hour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to check if a date is more than 24 hour? and if it s so show the date as "Month / day" format

Comment: so subtract the date from current time and see if it is greater than 24....

Comment: there is always a way ;)

Comment: How is your date format ? what is the date to check, you need to be more specific :)

Comment: so you are getting the date and displaying it again in a different format? why don't you get the date in mm/dd format?

Comment: in fact, I am using moment js library. so i came with this solution and work well `lessThanOneDay(date) {
    return Moment.unix(date).isAfter(Moment().subtract(24, 'hours'));
  }`

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple way of doing that.

Depends how the format of your date is. The best to me is to put everything in timeStamp by using the getTime() method

```
const yourDateMilliseconds = yourDate.getTime()
const actualTimeMilliseconds = new Date().getTime()
if (actualTimeMilliseconds - yourDateMilliseconds > 86400000) {
  console.log(yourDate)
}
```

You can find all about the method Date : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

This is without a lib. If you want you can add momentJS to your project which give you method to directly put the format you want and compare quickly, also manage timeZone : https://momentjs.com/

But use it only if you really need it because it's a heavy module, or try to destructure as much as possible to make the weight of your app lighter and only use what you need :

```
import { format } from 'moment'
```

Comment: I used this solution and its work fine :    check if its less than a day           `lessThanOneDay(date) {
    return Moment.unix(date).isAfter(Moment().subtract(24, 'hours'));
  }`

Comment: happy that moment helped you ! hope it will help other as well ! you can select my answer so that people will directly see where is the answer.